# Configure Php-fpm nginx mysql memory usage is low

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, server

I have 256GB Ram, but it's always around 16gb usage and my responses take too long to attempt but my cpu usage is 100%, how i can tell php fpm and nginx and mysql to use memory to help to responses

Note: i have 12 core cpus and ssd harddrive

My htop:

[image: htop]

And my fpm configure:

```
  pm.start_servers = 5

pm.max_children = 1000

    pm.min_spare_servers = 2

    pm.max_spare_servers = 6
```

My nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 12;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

events {
    worker_connections 1000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;

}
```

Comment: Not totally relevant, but how do you manage to use 100% cpu on all cores?! :)

Comment: @Jite we dont know too

Comment: I think that is the first thing to check. If you get the CPU usage down, your services will be able to use more cpu hence respond faster!

Comment: when i decrease the max_children of php-fpm the cpu usage goiyng done but to diffrence in response time @jide